# Non-numerical use of "один"

Tags: словоупотребление

I found the following sentence in which один occurs in a plural form and in conjunction with a plural noun. I had to deduce that it is being used in a non-numerical way, perhaps with a meaning like *only*.

> От них у меня **одни** неприятности.

That being the case, is this considered an adverb or a particle?

Also, is it on the level of **только** or **всего**, and if so, does it bear the same sentential stress that these words would in a similar sentence? Or does it bear a secondary stress like a number would?

Comment: "От них у меня один неприятности." is ungrammatical

Comment: It's a typo. There should be одни.

Comment: oops, my mistake...

Comment: It's best to think of один as an adjective that sometimes has the properties of a noun. The endings are adjectival in most cases too. Also "one" is singular, only etc, in extended form, no? —extended meanings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here *Одни* is used as an adjective with the meaning close to "*Nothing but*", so it's in plural.

> is it on the level of только or всего

*Всего* means rather a different thing. *Только* is certainly OK, but *Одни* sounds a bit stronger. I guess, "*Nothing but*" vs "*Only*" is a decently good analogy.